# How can I place objects over the surface of HDRI?

Tags: hdri

I want my objects to be perfectly aligned with the HDRI as if the object is sitting on the ground. when I set an environmental texture to blenderworld, the objects float in the middle of nowhere. So I want to know, how can I fix this issue ?

[image]

as you can see in this image the object is perfectly lining up with the HDRI.

Comment: I guess you need to create a floor

Comment: HDRIs aren't really meant to be a floor, but CGMatter has a video on projecting an hdri onto an object here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsAUfQlZH_w

Comment: Check out this tutorial video. He explains a very good method to do what you're looking for. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsAUfQlZH_w&t=0s

Comment: Instead of having users go through links just to understand your 
question, use the tools on the site to upload images directly.  See 
[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] 
link at the bottom of your question 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). You have better chances of 
getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page.

Answer (score 2):

create a plane under your object and keep it as shadow catcher... Search on Youtube for ***Shadowcatcher***